# Spray effect on a Canvas

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I've got this Canvas defined in XAML:

```
<Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas" Background="White" TouchMove="MyCanvas_TouchMove"/>
```

And here's my first try to simulate a spray effect during TouchMove events :

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {                
            double r = random.NextDouble() * radius;
            double theta = random.NextDouble() * (Math.PI * 2);
            double x = e.GetTouchPoint(MyCanvas).Position.X + Math.Cos(theta) * r;
            double y = e.GetTouchPoint(MyCanvas).Position.Y + Math.Sin(theta) * r;
            Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
            ellipse.Height = 2;
            ellipse.Width = 2;
            ellipse.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, x);
            ellipse.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, y);
            ellipse.Fill = (blackBrush);
            MyCanvas.Children.Add(ellipse);
        }
    }
```

It works great at the beginning, but the more I "spray", the rendering slows dramatically.

I'm aware that the problem is most likely because I add a lot of elements on the canvas, and also because the Children.Add method is called too often.

How can I improve this ?

Comment: Maybe use a writeable bitmap?  That way you can spray as much as you want and the memory usage will not grow.

Comment: I recently answered similar issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976163/speed-up-adding-objects-to-canvas-in-wpf/23976355#23976355, this is about speeding up the rendering in canvas